# SVG CSS content in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I have SVG icons in the CSS of my webpage.  They show and are responsive in Chrome and Safari, but do not show at all in Firefox.   Is the problem in the way that I link to the SVGs with `content:url` and is there a workaround?

CSS:

```
    #about-linked{
      content:url('./info.svg');
      position: absolute;
      background-color: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.0);
      z-index: 10;
      border-radius: 5px;
      bottom: 1%;
      left: 1%;
      height: 35px;
      width: 35px;
      opacity: 0.7;
      display: none
    }

    #about-linked:hover{
      cursor: pointer;
      opacity: 0.9;
  }

#changeLayer{
  content:url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pixel-perfect-at-16px-volume-1/16/5049-512.png);
    position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.0);
  z-index: 3;
  border-radius: 5px;
    top: 10%;
  left: 26%;
    height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div id='map'>
    <div id='program_title'>
        <span id="myspan">TITLE</span>
    </div>

    <div id ='about-linked'></div>
  </div>

<div id='changeLayer'></div>
```

NOTE:  changing to `content` to `background-image` produces and undesirable pattern as opposed to an icon:  For example (in Chrome) with `content:`, I get:

[image]

but with `background-image:` I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` only works with `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements. Other browsers may support it but that's [against official documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp).

The good news is that the only change you need to make is:

```
#changeLayer::before{
    ...
```

Comment: with the `#changeLayer` icon, when I use `::before`, the image becomes huge and takes up half of the screen...

Comment: Is there a reason you're loading these via content as opposed to background image in the first place?

Comment: Check the updated question - it's because I get a background fill pattern instead of an icon.

Comment: Look into background image properties, they are far more flexible than content. You can set background-repeat: none; as well as background-size: cover; etc